# Playstore rejects ionic (cordova) application due to SslErrorHandler

Tags: cordova, ionic3, android-security, cordova-android, sslerrorhandler

[image: Plugins]

Apart from above I am using this plugin :-
https://github.com/etabard/Cordova-OverAppBrowser

I recently tried to submit my ionic (cordova) application but it get rejected with below resons :-

Vulnerability : SSL Error Handler
For more information on how to address WebView SSL Error Handler alerts, please see this Google Help Center article.

https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7071387

```
Verions :

ionic :3.19.0
cordova-cli :- 6.5.0
cordova-android :- ~7.0.0
```

Only related code in cordova-android plugin I found in file SystemWebViewClient.java under cordova engine is:-

```
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        final String packageName = parentEngine.cordova.getActivity().getPackageName();
        final PackageManager pm = parentEngine.cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager();

        ApplicationInfo appInfo;
        try {
            appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0) {
                // debug = true
                handler.proceed();
                return;
            } else {
                // debug = false
                super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // When it doubt, lock it out!
            super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
        }
}
```

Is anything require to get rid of this error?

Comment: are you using file-transfer plugin? if so, which version?

Comment: No I am not using that.

Comment: Search for onReceivedSslError in your project

Comment: I edited question.

Comment: that's strange, it only proceed in debug mode, so shouldn't affect the google review

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? we have the same problem at the moment (already checked the file-transfer plugin..